# How do I aggregate values respect to some conceptual classes with SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, classification, aggregation

The problem I want to approach is the classification of some values for to extract some knowledge by SQL.

The sql solution that it is going to propose can be applied to a classification system composed by few classes

We are going to consider a simple case, an aggregation by a hierarchical sorting. In particular, our classification 
system will be composed by several classes, each of them will correspond to the class of a certain number of days 
lesser than of a different quantity.

The number of classes should be very limited.

For example: the class composed by all days lesser than seven, the class composed by all days lesser than six, 
the class composed by all days lesser than five, and so on...

I was inspired by a question on stack overflow.. [Aggregation of Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711410/aggregation-of-data)

The sql we're going to use is the version implemented on mysql dbms. 
For the examples reported in the answer, you can use SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Aggregation of values based upon a classification system in SQL**

To approach a such kind of problem, with the defined constraints in our question, we can start to consider our 
classification system that will consists of some table records, that represent the classes that we'll consider 
to carry out our compute, our referencing system.

Our target is compute some values based upon our classes, for each class we want to know a percentage of something..

***So, let's create our table of classes..***

Table "Classes" of the problem.

```
 Class         Reference_Score 
----------------------------
   1              1800      
   3              1800      
   5              1800      
   7              1800
```

Each record of this table represents the class of all values lesser then the value of the field "Class":

..and then our "Scores"

```
some_order   order_score
--------------------------
   1           90
   3           80
   4          560
   6          980
   7         1050
```

ok.. we want to know the percentage score of each class, that is the rapport from the sum of all the scores 
that belong to the class with the score assigned to the class, our reference score:

```
percentage_score = ( SUM(order_score)/Reference_Score ) * 100
```

***ok let's start..*** (the sql that follows is the implementation of MySql Dbms)

> *1. the first thing is to assign flags to each value of our scores by order:*

```
    select
    Scores.some_order, Scores.order_score,
    case when Scores.some_order <= 7 then '1_7' else '' end seven,
    case when Scores.some_order <= 6 then '1_6' else '' end six,
    case when Scores.some_order <= 5 then '1_5' else '' end five,
    case when Scores.some_order <= 4 then '1_4' else '' end four,
    case when Scores.some_order <= 3 then '1_3' else '' end three,
    case when Scores.some_order <= 2 then '1_2' else '' end two,
    case when Scores.some_order <= 1 then '1_1' else '' end one
    FROM Scores


this is the result:
```

---

```
    | some_order | order_score | seven | six | five | four | three | two | one |
    |------------|-------------|-------|-----|------|------|-------|-----|-----|
    |          1 |          90 |   1_7 | 1_6 |  1_5 |  1_4 |   1_3 | 1_2 | 1_1 |
    |          3 |          80 |   1_7 | 1_6 |  1_5 |  1_4 |   1_3 |     |     |
    |          4 |         560 |   1_7 | 1_6 |  1_5 |  1_4 |       |     |     |
    |          6 |         980 |   1_7 | 1_6 |      |      |       |     |     |
    |          7 |        1050 |   1_7 |     |      |      |       |     |     |
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> *2. now, we can start to calculate the sum of each score and put this sum in computed field, each of whom represents a class of our problem, and the table records we'll get out, represent the score by omogeneous class*:

```
select
case when Scores_Flagged.seven = '1_7' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_seven,
case when Scores_Flagged.six   = '1_6' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_six,
case when Scores_Flagged.five  = '1_5' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_five,
case when Scores_Flagged.four  = '1_4' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_four,
case when Scores_Flagged.three = '1_3' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_three,
case when Scores_Flagged.two   = '1_2' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_two,
case when Scores_Flagged.one   = '1_1' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_one
from
(
  select
  Scores.some_order, Scores.order_score,
  case when Scores.some_order <= 7 then '1_7' else '' end seven,
  case when Scores.some_order <= 6 then '1_6' else '' end six,
  case when Scores.some_order <= 5 then '1_5' else '' end five,
  case when Scores.some_order <= 4 then '1_4' else '' end four,
  case when Scores.some_order <= 3 then '1_3' else '' end three,
  case when Scores.some_order <= 2 then '1_2' else '' end two,
  case when Scores.some_order <= 1 then '1_1' else '' end one
  FROM Scores
) Scores_Flagged
group by seven, six, five, four, three, two, one
```

---

```
    | tot_seven | tot_six | tot_five | tot_four | tot_three | tot_two | tot_one |
    |-----------|---------|----------|----------|-----------|---------|---------|
    |      1050 |       0 |        0 |        0 |         0 |       0 |       0 |
    |       980 |     980 |        0 |        0 |         0 |       0 |       0 |
    |       560 |     560 |      560 |      560 |         0 |       0 |       0 |
    |        80 |      80 |       80 |       80 |        80 |       0 |       0 |
    |        90 |      90 |       90 |       90 |        90 |      90 |      90 |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> *3. at this point, let'get the total scores for omogeneous classes, who they will be the basis of our compute*:

```
select 
    sum(Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_seven) tot_seven,
    sum(Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_six) tot_six,
    sum(Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_five) tot_five,
    sum(Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_four) tot_four,
    sum(Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_three) tot_three,
    sum(Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_two) tot_two,
    sum(Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_one) tot_one
    from
    (
      select
      case when Scores_Flagged.seven = '1_7' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_seven,
      case when Scores_Flagged.six   = '1_6' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_six,
      case when Scores_Flagged.five  = '1_5' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_five,
      case when Scores_Flagged.four  = '1_4' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_four,
      case when Scores_Flagged.three = '1_3' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_three,
      case when Scores_Flagged.two   = '1_2' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_two,
      case when Scores_Flagged.one   = '1_1' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_one
      from
      (
        select
        Scores.some_order, Scores.order_score,
        case when Scores.some_order <= 7 then '1_7' else '' end seven,
        case when Scores.some_order <= 6 then '1_6' else '' end six,
        case when Scores.some_order <= 5 then '1_5' else '' end five,
        case when Scores.some_order <= 4 then '1_4' else '' end four,
        case when Scores.some_order <= 3 then '1_3' else '' end three,
        case when Scores.some_order <= 2 then '1_2' else '' end two,
        case when Scores.some_order <= 1 then '1_1' else '' end one
        FROM Scores
      ) Scores_Flagged
      group by seven, six, five, four, three, two, one
     )Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes
```

---

```
    | tot_seven | tot_six | tot_five | tot_four | tot_three | tot_two | tot_one |
    |-----------|---------|----------|----------|-----------|---------|---------|
    |      2760 |    1710 |      730 |      730 |       170 |      90 |      90 |    
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> *4. and finally, let's evaluate our intedend value (in this case a percentage) by each class:*:

```
    select 
    Classes.Class,
        case 
          when Classes.Class = 7 
          then cast((Total_Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_seven/Classes.Reference_Score) * 100 as decimal(5,2)) 
          when Classes.Class = 6 
          then cast((Total_Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_six/Classes.Reference_Score) * 100 as decimal(5,2)) 
          when Classes.Class = 5 
          then cast((Total_Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_five/Classes.Reference_Score) * 100 as decimal(5,2)) 
          when Classes.Class = 4 
          then cast((Total_Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_four/Classes.Reference_Score) * 100 as decimal(5,2)) 
          when Classes.Class = 3 
          then cast((Total_Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_three/Classes.Reference_Score) * 100 as decimal(5,2)) 
          when Classes.Class = 2 
          then cast((Total_Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_two/Classes.Reference_Score) * 100 as decimal(5,2)) 
          when Classes.Class = 1
          then cast((Total_Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_one/Classes.Reference_Score) * 100 as decimal(5,2)) 
          else 0 
        end Percentage_Score
    from Classes
    inner join 
    (
      select 
        sum(Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_seven) tot_seven,
        sum(Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_six) tot_six,
        sum(Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_five) tot_five,
        sum(Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_four) tot_four,
        sum(Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_three) tot_three,
        sum(Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_two) tot_two,
        sum(Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes.tot_one) tot_one
        from
        (
          select
          case when Scores_Flagged.seven = '1_7' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_seven,
          case when Scores_Flagged.six   = '1_6' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_six,
          case when Scores_Flagged.five  = '1_5' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_five,
          case when Scores_Flagged.four  = '1_4' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_four,
          case when Scores_Flagged.three = '1_3' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_three,
          case when Scores_Flagged.two   = '1_2' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_two,
          case when Scores_Flagged.one   = '1_1' then sum(Scores_Flagged.order_score) else 0 end tot_one
          from
          (
            select
            Scores.some_order, Scores.order_score,
            case when Scores.some_order <= 7 then '1_7' else '' end seven,
            case when Scores.some_order <= 6 then '1_6' else '' end six,
            case when Scores.some_order <= 5 then '1_5' else '' end five,
            case when Scores.some_order <= 4 then '1_4' else '' end four,
            case when Scores.some_order <= 3 then '1_3' else '' end three,
            case when Scores.some_order <= 2 then '1_2' else '' end two,
            case when Scores.some_order <= 1 then '1_1' else '' end one
            FROM Scores
          ) Scores_Flagged
          group by seven, six, five, four, three, two, one
         )Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes
    ) Total_Scores_by_Omogeneous_Classes
```

> ***5. We have our attended result***:

---

```
| Class | Percentage_Score |
|-------|------------------|
|     1 |                5 |
|     3 |             9.44 |
|     5 |            40.56 |
|     7 |           153.33 |
----------------------------
```

> *We can also add multiple reference scores for the same classes, and so can have several percentages related upon more reference scores*:

```
for example:

 Class         Reference_Score 
----------------------------
   1              1800      
   3              1800      
   5              1800      
   7              1800      
   1              3600      
   3              3600      
   5              3600      
   7              3600    


 --------------------------
| Class | Percentage_Score |
|-------|------------------|
|     1 |                5 |
|     3 |             9.44 |
|     5 |            40.56 |
|     7 |           153.33 |
|     1 |              2.5 |
|     3 |             4.72 |
|     5 |            20.28 |
|     7 |            76.67 |       
----------------------------
```